# Write to file failing

Tags: c

My write is failing and returning a value of `-1`. I just want to append a character to the file.
I am not sure what is failing and where it is failing.

After running the code, the return value for open was `3` and for write `-1`. The file is getting created, but not being written to.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{ 
    int fd,j;
    fd = open("test.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND,0777);
    printf("%d\n",fd);
    j = write(fd,"A",1);
    printf("write return %d\n",j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the return value of `open` and `write`, and if they fail use `perror` to print the associated error message.

Comment: Add `#include <errno.h>` and check the value of `errno` (a global `int` value) after `write()` fails.  And to be pedantic, `write()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.

Comment: I guess if we had O_WR and O_RD and they were combinable into `O_RDWR`, then `O_APPEND` could simply contain O_WR in itself, and you wouldn't have your usage problem. But that's not how things are and we have `O_RDONLY` and `O_WRONLY` instead of O_RD and O_WR and so `O_APPEND` can't know which of the two you want. I honestly wonder why that is.

Comment: Thanks, adding the O_WRONLY, fixed the issue, i had put errno and got segmentation fault without the above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and use the preview pane to verify, that your code is well indented. If you expect help from us, we expect some effort from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `O_WRONLY` (or `O_RDWR`) to the `open` call.

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int fd,j;
    fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,0777);
    if(0>fd) perror(0);
    printf("%d\n",fd);
    j=write(fd,"A",1);
    printf("write return %d\n",j);
    if(0>j) perror(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the O_WRONLY, fixed the issue, i had put errno and got segmentation fault without the above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @S.Kartik if this answer helped you fix your problem, then it would be much appreciated if you would click the gray check mark next to the vote count to **accept the answer**

Comment: Hi @Tau: I did vote, but given my reputation of less than 15, though the vote got recorded, will not be shown publicly is the message that I got.

Comment: @S.Kartik read my comment carefully.  to ***accept an answer***, click the gray *check mark* next to the vote count, not the gray *triangles*

Comment: @Tau: Hi Tau, sorry my bad! Done, clicked on the green tick mark. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @PSkocik, you need to add the flag `WRONLY`.  Also, check for errors, `errno` in particular:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

j = write(fd, "A", 1);
printf("write return %d\n", j);
printf("errno: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
```

```
write return -1
errno: 9 Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the O_WRONLY, fixed the issue, i had put errno and got segmentation fault without the above. Thanks a lot.